# Emulating an older OS to use printer on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, drivers, printer

I've searched the internet inside out for windows 7 compatible drivers for my printer HP Color LaserJet 3550. I've also tried using a version lower and higher drivers to no avail. Windows 7 still doesn't recognize the printer.

I have two computers, my old one and one of my friend's. My old computer runs on vista 32 bit and the other one on windows 7 32 bit, which I am currently using. Every time I need to print something I have to crawl under my desk to switch cables and boot my old computer which takes forever.

Only option I can come up any more is to use virtualbox and emulate older OS and use the printer through there, but I have no idea if it works?

Comment: I was under the impression that in Windows the "server" PC only provides the connection to the printer while the "client" PC does all the generation of data for the printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Vista and Windows 7 use a similar driverbase. You should be able to install the windows vista drivers on windows 7 without much hastle.

Otherwise, try Universal Print drivers. They often work although it may reduce functionality (eg, not being able to select tray 3 and higher.)